# Nginx: upstream server directive with regex

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, load-balancing, docker-compose

I've got a docker-based architecture: A configurable number of containers being load balanced by one nginx container. All of these containers exist on the same local network, `backend` (created by `docker-compose`).

The containers I want to load balance will always listen on port `77894`, and will always have a name of the form `model_*` (where the `*` could be any positive integer). The `nginx.conf` in the single nginx container needs to be configured correctly.

This `nginx.conf` works fine, but I have to specify each replica of `model` explicitly in the `upstream` service:

```
http {

    upstream models {
        server model_1:77894;
        server model_2:77894;
        server model_3:77894;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://models;
        }
    }
}


events { }
```

This is not dynamic; I would have to know the number of replicas of `model_*` beforehand.

When I try this (and other variants):

```
upstream {
    server ~ ^model_[0-9]:77894
}
```

nginx throws an error: `invalid parameter "^model_[0-9]:77894" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:4`

Is there any way to tell nginx to reverse proxy to all containers with names like `model_*:77894`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `server` directive supports only explicit upstream IP address:port pairs or Unix domain socket paths.

You should use a configuration management system, which updates nginx configuration file and sets up containers at the same time, therefore always keeping nginx configuration in sync.

One option is to add all possible `server` entries in the `upstream` section and let nginx detect if backend is available or not. If nginx tries to use non-existing backends too often, `fail_timeout` value can be increased from the default 10 second value.